# jQuery AJAX multiple functions for the get result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am in C# .NET using jQuery AJAX, as per the following, which works great:

```
 var str = "/api/GetPatient/GetPatient/" + $('#name1').val();

 var r = $.get(str, function (data) {
   $("h3").append("You are looking for " + data.name + " ?")
 },"json");
```

My issue is that I want to update not just one element, but there are actually several elements I would like to update.  The obvious solution I suppose is to just create a class and then update the class instead of just `<h3>`'s.
Nevertheless, I still wish to throw the question out there because I haven't encountered the question before, and it might be something useful to do.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is unclear, what are the elements you are trying to update? At the moment you code just appends some text, it doesn't update anything.

Comment: I am updating <h3></h3>   The result will be <h3>You are looking for, etc etc etc</h3>    I guess I thought that was considered an update, maybe not the precise term though

Comment: Are you saying you want to put the same value into multiple elements? Or that you want to make multiple Ajax calls for different patients and put the results into different elements?

Comment: I have one value, and I wish to do multiple things with that value.  For example, the code { $("h3").append("You are 
   looking for " + data.name + " ?")}  has only one action right now, but I wish to insert multiple actions, but there are no semicolons so I'm not sure how I would format this

Comment: I have edited the question to format the code "properly", i.e., to put some line breaks. Note that this is a change to white-space only that will not affect the result at all. But now perhaps you can see that the part doing the `.append()` is just one line inside a function. You can add more lines to that function if you want to do more things with `data`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is a Javascript question then - can you give an example of how to format putting more lines?  The thing that confuses me is that there is no semi-colon, i.e. "data.name + " ?");"

Comment: like you said you can create a common class and and update the class or just add more append functions. :- 
`var str = "/api/GetPatient/GetPatient/" + $('#name1').val();

 var r = $.get(str, function (data) {
   $("h3").append("You are looking for " + data.name + " ?");
   $("h4").append("You are looking for " + data.name + " ?");
   $("h5").append("You are looking for " + data.name + " ?");
 },"json");`

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Use as many jQuery calls as you wish, and be sure to separate them with semi-colons.